# PhpStorm colors of variables in class

Tags: phpstorm

When I declare private variable inside class

```
class Class
{        
    private $_myVariable;
....
```

I have [PRS2 error](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#42-properties):

> Property names SHOULD NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate protected or private visibility.

I agree with that but when I use `$this->myVariable` how can I know exactly if it's public or private? can I set different colors for different types of variables(public, protected, private)? Or any other ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start typing the name of the variable, PHPStorm will handily give you an indication of what the variable type is:
[image: PHPStorm variable hinting]

- A private variable has a red, closed padlock
- A public variable has a green, opened padlock
- A protected variable has a key

I've not found a way of setting them to have a different colour in the editor depending on type.  They fall under the colour category of 'Variables', probably to save confusion within the editor.  For instance, if you had the following code:

```
class TestClass {
    private $variablePrivate;
    public $variablePublic;
    protected $variableProtected;

    public function bad_code() {
        $variablePrivate = 'test';
        self::$variablePrivate = $variablePrivate;
    }

}
```

It could be difficult for the editor to know which `$variablePrivate` you mean, or even if they are supposed to be the same variable, but you've made a mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a gave me the good advice. Next time I will use PhpStorm hints.